# C# Registry write no longer works

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

We've just noticed that we can no longer write to the registry from an C# http handler (**.ashx**).  I've seen many posts here but think I've exhausted every one. Big difference is that this code **has been operational for years** but is just now giving the error:

> "requested registry access is not allowed".

What used to work:

```
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(strPath, 
    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

I've tried many other combinations all with the same result:

```
RegistryKey regKey = null;
RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.FullControl;
regKey = thisKey.OpenSubKey(strPath, true);
regKey = thisKey.OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
regKey = thisKey.OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, rights);

if (bit64)
{
    regKey = RegistryKey
        .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, rights);
}
else
{
    regKey = RegistryKey
        .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
        .OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
}

regKey = thisKey.OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
regKey = thisKey.OpenSubKey(strPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, rights);
```

I've also tried adding an app.config file:

```
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
   <security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

All fail as soon as it tries to open the subkey.  I've even set the application pool to use "Administrator" just to see if that helps and it doesn't.  What else can I try or what additional information can I provide?

### EDIT #1:

Keep in mind that this is a *web* application.  Our desktop programs that use the same code still work fine.  The error is on `OpenSubKey` and it doesn't go further so no "write" code is shown.

Comment: Error message? ..

Comment: Even without the message, I can make an educated guess.  It's a new security feature.

Comment: The original line of code you have works for me. I noticed that you said *"we can no longer write to the registry"*, yet you have only showed code that reads from the registry. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: Error message is in the text.  now giving the error: "requested registry access is not allowed".  I am trying to write, however that error doesn't let me get that far.  It happens as soon as I call OpenSubKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regedit and gave "Everyone" full permissions on the desired registry key.  That worked with a number of the different options listed above.  Fortunately, all the values I read and write are under one key.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Did you upgrade the OS?  Service Pack?  There might have been a security update that could explain why it no longer works.